# How to save images from web in Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

In my application I have list of urls to images. And what I need to do is download this images and save them in Isolated Storage.

What I already have:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile localFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
...
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(item.url, UriKind.Absolute);

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = localFile.CreateFile(GetFileName(item.url)))//escape file name
    {
        wb.SaveJpeg(fs, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
    }
}
...
}
```

This code have place inside function in my `App.xaml.cs` file. I have tried many solutions, in this one the problem is "Invalid cross-thread access".

How can I make it work?

Comment: I've never put any code in App.xaml.cs, do you use MVVM ? Can you put it in the View model or a model ?
Else you could try to use the [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: In 'App.xaml.cs' I have global function which I use in whole application. Dispatcher doesn't work for me in this file.

Comment: Can't you declare it static in a model ?

Comment: Declare what? And what do you mean by model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem is:

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(item.url, UriKind.Absolute);
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.BeginGetResponse((ar) =>
    {
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var name = GetFileName(item.url);
                if (localFile.FileExists(name))
                {
                    localFile.DeleteFile(name);
                }
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = localFile.CreateFile(name))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fs);
                }
            }
        });
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get invalid cross-thread access if you create `WriteableBitmap` on non-UI thread. Ensure that that code is run on the main thread by using `Dispatcher`:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    // ...
);
```

Comment: I have tried this but then it thrown "Invalid pointer" exception.

Answer (score 0):

@Mateusz Rogulski

You should use WebClient, and i suggest you following solution for your problem. just try.

```
 public string YourMethod(string yoursUri)
 {
    BitmapImage image=new BitmapImage();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.OpenReadCompleted += async (o, args) =>
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        await args.Result.CopyToAsync(stream);
        image.SetSource(stream);
    };
    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(yoursUri));//if passing object than you can write myObj.yoursUri
    return image;
}
```

now you have image and you can save into your isolatedStorage with valid checks wherever you call this function